# HTML proper div sizing

Tags: html, css

When making a div `width:100%` of its parent and then applying a `padding-right:5%;` to it, it will be just as if I made the `width:105%;` on the div, and that is affecting other divs that are floated beside it in cases such as `width:70%; padding-right:2%; float:left`

Let's assume we have this code

```html
<div style="width:100%; padding-right:3%;"> text </div>
```

This will create a horizontal scroll bar on the page because basically the div's width is more than 100% now. My question is, how to properly size divs? do I have to subtract the actual div's `padding` from its `width` or what? That's what I'm doing now and it's working, but I feel like that's not the best approach.

Comment: may be you can add an inline tag to text. i.e. <div style="width:100%;" > <span style=" padding-right:3%;" text </span> </div>

Comment: Look into `box-sizing: border-box`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to the element's style:

```html
  <div style="width: 100%; padding-right: 3%; box-sizing: border-box;"> text </div>
```

According to MDN:

> **border-box**
>
> The width and height properties include the content, the padding and border, but not the margin.

Comment: @MarwanAK - You should avoid using inline styles (and inline javascript) because doing that explodes the number of places that need to be changed if you start changing the look of your site.  Use `<style></style>` blocks or, even better, use `.css` stylesheet files.